# Can I install gapps after I have finished installing the new ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-apps

I have recently installed a new ROM on my Galaxy S3 and I did not flash gapps with the ROM itself. Can I go to reboot mode and flash gapps even after I installed the ROM?

Comment: Yep, go back to recovery and flash the correct Gapps, wipe cache partition and you are good to go!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that. First make sure you [download the correct version](http://goo.im/gapps) (the version of the GApps archive must match the Android version installed on your device). Put the `gapps*.zip` file on your SDCard, and boot to [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode). Select "Install update.zip", and navigate to your GApps archive. Select it, have it installed, reboot, enjoy :)

As you've tagged your question [cyanogenmod](/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod), you might also wish to take a look at [their GApps page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Gapps). This will make it easier for you to find the correct GApps archive.

Answer (score 1):

Flash it using recovery, but you will need to wipe your cache's after flashing or gapps will crash, therefore making your phone unusable and forcing you to wipe.